# reducing amount of text in a summary

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css

often in web sites such as with recipes one sees a large amount of text(the recipe method for example) of which not all the text is displayed with a 'more...' hyperlink which one can click on to display everything.

I am trying to do something similar but as I have it at the moment I apply the height property on a the relevant div element which cuts the amount of text of instead.

```
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<div class='productList summaryContainer'>";
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<div class='productListTumbnail'>";
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<img src ='Images/ScreenShots/" + productCode + ".jpg' alt='Health and Safety'>";
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "</div>";
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<div class='productListContent'>";
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<h3>" + productName + "</h3>";
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += summary;
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "</div>";
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "</div>";

.summaryContainer
{
height:120px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

This is far from ideal.
Can I perhaps have some help in extending summary text amount upon clicking on relevant hyperlink (e.g. more...) or perhaps just a good way of reducing a certain amount of text (html) and then to redirect to a different page upon clicking the relevant hyperlink.

Comment: you can use a combination of Jordan Trudgett & pouki06 answers. you can limit the text displayed if it is over a certain size and add a more button. then when the more buttom is clicked you can insert all the text into a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to implement a simple hidden block.

```
<p>Here is the start of my text. Some more text will follow after you click the "More" link.</p>
<span id="moreLink"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="$('#moreLink').hide(); $('#moreStuff').show();">More...</a></span>
<div id="moreStuff" style="display: none;">
    <p>Here is the body of the text. Some more text here. This stuff is initially hidden. You can put more text in here, etc.</p>
    <p>Another paragraph inside the body.</p>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jKsda/)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [Substring Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
summary.Substring(0, 200) //Prints 200 first chars.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using jQuery?

Its just as simple as that:

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    $('#content').toggle();
});

<a id="more">more</a>
<div id="content" style="display:none;">lot of text</div>
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/